# std::string compare( ) giving segmentation fault:

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, compare

So I am making a function that will add a new string to a vector of strings ONLY IF the string is a unique string not already contained in the vector. Here is my code:

```
void CityMapper::addToVector(string& s)
{
    bool newWord = true;
    if(numAirports > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numAirports; i++)
        {
            if(airportNames[i].compare(s) == 0)
                newWord = false;
        }
    }
    if(newWord == true)
    {
        airportNames.pushBack(s);
        numAirports++;
    }
}
```

airportNames is the vector of strings. When I run the program, it segfaults with the following errors in Valgrind:

```
Process Terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
```

Before this happens, This error appears in the Valgrind terminal:

```
Invalid Read of Size 8
```

Both are happening at the string.compare() line. Does anyone know why this would be happening? I also tried the function without the & symbol in the parameters.

**EDIT:** I took Derek's advice and made all of his changes. Now the program is segfaulting at a different method where I read in the strings from a file. Here is the code for that function:

```
void CityMapper::getCities()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(flightDataFile);
    fin >> numAirports;
    string tempCity1, tempCity2, tossout;
    while(getline(fin, tempCity1, ','))
    {
        fin.ignore(1);
        getline(fin, tempCity2, ',');
        fin.ignore(1);
        getline(fin, tossout, '\n');
        addToVector(tempCity1);
        addToVector(tempCity2);
    }
}
```

Here are the error messages from Valgrind:

```
==8357== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==8357==    at 0x4EF158B: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,     
std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==8357==    by 0x402214: CityMapper::getCities() (in 
/home/charlie/NetBeansProjects/Lab4/Lab4)
==8357==    by 0x401EB7: CityMapper::run() (in /home/charlie/NetBeansProjects/Lab4/Lab4)
==8357==    by 0x4050A0: main (in /home/charlie/NetBeansProjects/Lab4/Lab4)
==8357== 
==8357== Invalid read of size 4
==8357==    at 0x4EF158B: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==8357==    by 0x402214: CityMapper::getCities() (in   
/home/charlie/NetBeansProjects/Lab4/Lab4)
==8357==    by 0x401EB7: CityMapper::run() (in /home/charlie/NetBeansProjects/Lab4/Lab4)
==8357==    by 0x4050A0: main (in /home/charlie/NetBeansProjects/Lab4/Lab4)
==8357==  Address 0xfffffffffffffff8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==8357== 
==8357== 
==8357== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==8357==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8
==8357==    at 0x4EF158B: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==8357==    by 0x402214: CityMapper::getCities() (in 
/home/charlie/NetBeansProjects/Lab4/Lab4)
==8357==    by 0x401EB7: CityMapper::run() (in /home/charlie/NetBeansProjects/Lab4/Lab4)
==8357==    by 0x4050A0: main (in /home/charlie/NetBeansProjects/Lab4/Lab4)
```

Comment: Do you sure the size of `airportNames` is `numAirports` ?

Comment: Why do you need a separate variable instead of using `airportNames.size()`? That way you'll never have to worry about it getting out of sync.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to retain the airport names in their original order? If not, just an `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`. If you do need to retain the original order, still use the set to determine whether the name is "new".

Comment: try using airportNames.size(), also it should be airportNames.push_back(s); not airportNames.pushback(s)

Comment: This call to `.compare` does not make much sense; just do `newWord = airportNames[i] == s;`.

Comment: `if(newWord == true)` makes me cry.

Comment: You say `airportNames` is a vector. But `std::vector` doesn't have a member named `pushBack`.

Comment: `if ( find( airportNames.begin(), airportNames.end(), s ) == airportNames.end() ) { airportNames.push_back(s); }`

Comment: fin >> numAirports? Is the first line of your input file an integer representing the number of airports in the file? It may also help for you to include a simple version of the input file.

Answer (score 6):

`compare` will not cause a segmentation fault. It's the object you're trying to invoke it on that doesn't exist. As a general rule: Never store redundant information (`numAirports` in this case). If you have to store redundant information you should at least check for consistency. In the code you posted above a malformed input file will crash your application. Simply remove `numAirports` completely, you don't need it.

Instead, use the following:

```
void CityMapper::addUnique( const string& name )
{
    if ( std::find( airportNames.begin(), airportNames.end(), name )
         == airportNames.end() )
    {
        // Name does not yet exist -> add it
        airportNames.push_back( name );
    }
}
```

Things to note:

- The method has been renamed to reflect its semantics. You should not encode data types in a function name (vector).
- The signature has been changed to take a `const` reference. The method does not alter this parameter and that is how this is documented in a way the compiler can verify.
- The parameter name has been changed to `name`. After all, that's what it represents.
- The loop has been replaced with library code (`std::find`). Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

As pointed out in the comments, if there is no convincing reason to use `std::vector` you should probably have a look at [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). Both containers store **unique** objects so you don't have to write your own `addUnique`.

Comment: Great answer.  IMO this question really deserves a mention of `std::set` (like @JerryCoffin's comment), though.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use a `std::vector` for this (instead of a `std::unordered_set`):

```
void CityMapper::addToVector(const string& s) // you aren't changing the string, pass it by const-reference
{
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = std::find(airportNames.begin(), airportNames.end(), s);
    if (it == airportNames.end()) // not found, so unique
    {
        airportNames.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

`std::vector` has a size member (so `numAirports` is unnecessary), and using the `std::find` function eliminates the extra conditional checks.

Alternatively, you could use a `std::unordered_set` or `std::set` and avoid the `std::find` operation entirely (though, this would use more memory):

```
void CityMapper::addToVector(const string& s)
{
    std::set<std::string> airports(airportNames.begin(), airportNames.end());
    airports.insert(s);
    airportNames.assign(airports.begin(), airports.end());
}
```

And the better solution would be to simply store the data in a set to begin with:

```
void CityMapper::addUnique(const string& s)
{
    // assume airportNames is defined as a std::set<std::string>
    airportNames.insert(s);
}
```

But to your original question:  The seg fault is likely due to the fact that you are not using the `std::vector`'s actual size, but instead storing a separate `numAirports` value (that likely is not being kept in sync, and is unnecessary if you make the changes mentioned above), so when you attempt to access memory that is not allocated to the vector (and potentially not allocated at all), you are invoking undefined behavior.  All of which goes away with better code.

**EDIT**

With your additional information, it should also be noted that your `getCities` function can be greatly simplified:

```
struct line_reader : std::ctype<char>
{
    line_reader() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> rc(table_size, std::ctype_base::mask());
        rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc[','] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc[' '] = std::ctype_base::alpha; // allowing city names with spaces
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

void CityMapper::getCities()
{
    ifstream fin(flightDataFile);
    line_reader reader;
    fin.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), &reader));
    // if using a set
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(fin), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::inserter(airportNames, airportNames.begin()));  

    // or, if using a vector
    // NOTE:  to keep this exception safe 
    // (e.g. keep the values in the actual vector unique even if something happens after we've read in the file data, 
    // pull the values into a temp vector and then swap
    std::vector<std::string> temp;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(fin), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::back_inserter(temp));
    std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    temp.erase(std::unique(temp.begin(), temp.end()), temp.end());
    std::swap(airportNames, temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to be this. 
I changed several things I'm using `airportNames.size()` which returns the number of elements in the airportNames vector. This will prevent any errors in the event a pop_back or remove has been called on the vector but numAirports was not updated. This is the most likely cause of the segfault.

I've also fixed what I hope is a typo with your `airportNames.push_back()` call. You had `airportNames.pushBack()` which is incorrect syntax.

And last of all is just a style thing but `newWord == true` is redundant just say `if( newWord)` both statements evaluate to true.

```
void CityMapper::addToVector(const string& s)
{
    bool newWord = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < airportNames.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(s == airportNames[i])
        newWord = false;
        break;
    }
    if(newWord)
    {
        airportNames.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggested edits: `1)` Rename `addToVector` to `addUnique`. `2)` Change it's signature to take a `const string&`. `3)` Use a `break;` statement in your `for`-loop. `4)` Remove both the `for`-loop and the local variable `newWord` and use `std::find` instead.

Comment: I made some of the changes. I try not to alter the original code to much but those are all good suggestions.

Comment: I just edited my code and posted the update in my original question, it is segfaulting in a new place. I'm also going to try and use other people's suggestions as well.